# What is the reason the code breaks when the input is asked?

Tags: python, function, physics

Hi im new to python and working on a small project:

I want to write a program to provide information on the height of a ball thrown straight up into the air. The program should request as input the initial height, h feet, and the initial velocity, v feet per second. The height of the ball after t seconds is h + vt - 16t2 feet. The program should perform the following two calculations:

(a) Determine the maximum height of the ball. Note: The ball will reach its maximum
height after v/32 seconds.
(b) Determine approximately when the ball will hit the ground. Hint: Calculate the height after every .1 second and determine when the height is no longer a positive number.
A function named getInput should be used to obtain the values of h and v and that function should call a function named isValid to ensure that the input values are positive numbers. Each of the tasks (a) and (b) should be carried out by functions

```
  def getInput():
        h = int(input("Enter the initial height of the ball: "))
        v = int(input("Enter the initial velocity of the ball: "))
        isValid(h,v)

    def isValid(h,v):
        if (h<= 0):
            print("Please enter positive values")

        elif(v<= 0):
            print("Please enter positive values")

        else:
            height = maxHeight(h,v)
            print("The maximum height of the ball is", height, "feet.")
            groundTime = ballTime(h,v)
            print("The ball will hit the ground after approximately", groundTime, "seconds.")


    def maxHeight(h,v):
        t = (v/32)
        maxH = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
        return maxH


    def ballTime(h,v):
        t = 0.1
        while(True):
            ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
            if (ballHeight <= 0):
                break
            else:
                t += 0.1

        return t

    getInput()
```

## The output I desire is:

```
> Enter the initial height of the ball: 5 
> Enter the initial velocity of the ball: 34 
-The maximum height of the ball is 23.06 feet. 
-The ball will hit the ground after approximately 2.27 seconds.
```

Comment: I ran this and it works on my system, can you post the error please.

Comment: @ari victor File "<ipython-input-83-9a18b8c191a0>", line 1
    elif(v<= 0):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Agreed - works just fine here: https://repl.it/repls/SalmonSubstantialObservation

Comment: I do not receive an output it just runs fine @rgk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using IPython? You might have to get rid of the spaces in between the elif and the if body before. It seems to finish interpreting the line right there and then, kind of how the Python interpreter would stop interpreting if you were to enter those lines in one by one.

```
 def getInput():
        h = int(input("Enter the initial height of the ball: "))
        v = int(input("Enter the initial velocity of the ball: "))
        isValid(h,v)

    def isValid(h,v):
        if (h<= 0):
            print("Please enter positive values")
        elif(v<= 0):
            print("Please enter positive values")
        else:
            height = maxHeight(h,v)
            print("The maximum height of the ball is", height, "feet.")
            groundTime = ballTime(h,v)
            print("The ball will hit the ground after approximately", groundTime, "seconds.")


    def maxHeight(h,v):
        t = (v/32)
        maxH = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
        return maxH


    def ballTime(h,v):
        t = 0.1
        while(True):
            ballHeight = (h + (v*t) - (16*t*t))
            if (ballHeight <= 0):
                break
            else:
                t += 0.1
        return t

    getInput()
```